Anime where a girl died and got reincarnated as a wingless fairy who is married
She died and was reincarnated as a fairy who is married and has no wings from an accident from what I remember I think she had white/bluish hair and I dont remember where I read it or anything please help.‍♀️‍♀️

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?

"I dont remember where I read it" That's an odd thing to say about an anime. Is this definitely an anime, or are you actually asking about a manga/manhwa/manhua here? And was it full colour or mostly black & white?

Full color manga/manhua??
